# C# perform string operation on UTF-16 byte array

Tags: c#, .net, performance, string, arrays

I'm reading a file into `byte[] buffer`. The file contains a lot of UTF-16 strings (millions) in the following format:

- The first byte contain and string length in chars (range 0 .. 255)
- The following bytes contains the string characters in UTF-16 encoding (each char represented by 2 bytes, means byteCount = charCount * 2).

I need to perform standard string operations for all strings in the file, for example: `IndexOf`, `EndsWith` and `StartsWith`, with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` and `StringComparison.Ordinal`.

For now my code first converting each string from byte array to `System.String` type. I found the following code to be the most efficient to do so:

```
// position/length validation removed to minimize the code

string result;
byte charLength = _buffer[_bufferI++];
int byteLength = charLength * 2;

fixed (byte* pBuffer = &_buffer[_bufferI])
{
    result = new string((char*)pBuffer, 0, charLength);
}

_bufferI += byteLength;
return result;
```

Still, `new string(char*, int, int)` it's very slow because it performing **unnecessary** copying **for each string**.

Profiler says its `System.String.wstrcpy(char*,char*,int32)` performing slow.

I need a way to perform string operations **without copying bytes for each string**.

Is there a way to perform string operations on byte array **directly**?

Is there a way to create new string **without** copying its bytes?

Comment: Not every character encodes to two bytes in UTF16.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That is true, but those characters are stored as multiple `char` values in the string also.

Comment: @Kerrek SB You are talking about code points. In Microsoft terminology a character is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't create a string without copying the character data.

The `String` object stores the meta data for the string (Length, et.c.) in the same memory area as the character data, so you can't keep the character data in the byte array and pretend that it's a `String` object.

You could try other ways of constructing the string from the byte data, and see if any of them has less overhead, like `Encoding.UTF16.GetString`.

If you are using a pointer, you could try to get multiple strings at a time, so that you don't have to fix the buffer for each string.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the File using a StreamReader using Encoding.UTF16 so you do not have the "byte overhead" in between:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF16)) 
{
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        //Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: `StreamReader` behind the scenes copying buffers (Saw in reflector).

Comment: @DxCK - There always be buffer copy. Have you actually tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create extension methods on byte arrays to handle most of those string operations directly on the byte array and avoid the cost of converting.  Not sure what all string operations you perform, so not sure if all of them could be accomplished this way.

Comment: how can one implement OrdinalIgnoreCase this way?

Comment: Hmm.  Good question.  That would probably require you to convert each byte to a character and compare those.  That could still potentially be faster than converting all items to a string first since you would only need to convert the number of characters required to make the compare operation find which set of inputs is less than or greater than the other.